# Why do we use "this other" in a sentence?

Tags: meaning

Why do we use "this other" at the beginning of a sentence?

For example in this sentence :

> This other car hit me while I was parking

Comment: I believe it's an idiom from the 1960s - at least in Britain that seemed to me to be the case. It makes no logical sense to use *this* because the thing in question is not in view of the interlocutor, who has not previously been introduced to it.  A more 'correct' form would be simply to say *Another car hit me whilst parking...*. But I suppose *this other car* helps draw attention to it as a specific car, according it an identity. I must confess to using the idiom myself and it seems to serve a purpose in getting the listener's attention to the vehicle (or other thing) in question.

Comment: What's a good question. I come cross this "And after you left, I couldn't stop thinking about you. There was this other case, and I thought we might cross paths, but we never did. I was hoping..."

Answer (score 2):

The word *this* is used here is as a *cataphoric* reference.

> **Cataphoric** reference means that a word in a text refers to another later in the text and you need to look forward to understand. It can be compared with anaphoric reference, which means a word refers back to another word for its meaning. [(TeachingEnglish)](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/cataphoric-reference)

*This* is often used in this way in spoken narratives to introduce a noun, especially a person, who is going to be repeatedly mentioned in the narrative. 
E.g. "This guy comes up to me..." signifies more than "A guy..." that this person is an important part of the story and I'm going to talk about him a lot.

For a full explanation of this phenomenon, see ["The cataphoric use of the indefinite this in spoken narratives"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4301436/)

Comment: *Cataphoric* originates as a term used to describe certain features of an electrical current. Its grammatical meaning seems only to date from the 1970s. (The OED's first example is 1976). This seems to support my hunch that the practice, in Britain, began in the 1960s. But I would be interested in hearing others' opinions on this.

Comment: I think not. Cataphoric is not restricted to the use of 'this'. The sentence "When he arrived home, John went to sleep" is an example of cataphora, since the pronoun 'he' comes before the noun John to which it refers.

Comment: Indeed. The OED records "anaphora"  as a grammatical term only from 1933, but it is one of the primary uses of pronouns, and goes back as far as we can trace. Cataphora is less common and less well described, but likewise occurs anciently.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you. Very interesting. As one who has never studied linguistics, nor grammar at anything above O Level, I am learning quite a lot. And I have just realised that that last sentence is cataphoric!

Answer (score -3):

"this other car" means there are many cars around that place, thus the person wants you to specify the car. That is showing that he knows that this specific car knocked him at the parking bay. He was going to park his car, and her friend or somebody somewhere knocked him. Maybe she was reversing or getting out of the parking bay. This shows that the other car made a mistake by hitting the person's car.

Comment: Hi @Susan Tirop, welcome to ELU. Your post is very poorly formatted with poor grammar, I've attempted to clean it up a bit. Users on this site tend to prefer clear statements with proper grammar and formatting.

Comment: “Alex was going to Moscow from Dubai and he had never mentioned a person named Miranda to this other Unisphere employee.” How about this?